# How to set a target group to a specific container on a multi-container service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Usually when I deploy an application using ECS, I create a task definition, add a container to it and then I create a service and specify the target group in the last step. I do that when I have one container in that service and it works as expected.

Now I have multiple containers in the same service. In all of them the container port is 3000 (host port is 0) and I have an Application load balancer that I can forward to a specific target group.

So assuming I have 5 containers and 5 target groups, how do I tell the load balancer to forward to a specific target group (that I created just for that container)?

In "container to load balance" section, I can only choose one:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are exposing multiple containers to different target groups, you can't do that through the web UI. You have to use a different tool like the AWS CLI, CloudFormation, Terraform, etc. Per [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html):

> To create a service specifying multiple target groups, you must create the service using the Amazon ECS API, SDK, AWS CLI, or an AWS CloudFormation template. After the service is created, you can view the service and the target groups registered to it with the AWS Management Console. You must use UpdateService to modify the load balancer configuration of an existing service.